# Name column alias from xml value stored in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, alias

I am trying to name an alias based on an xml value in another table. The value is defined by the user, so therefore cannot be named statically.

XML from table (table1) and column (TimeBuckets):

```
<buckets>
  <bucket id="1" name="Overnight to 3 Mths">
    <lower>0</lower>
    <upper>3</upper>
  </bucket>
</buckets>
```

I want to set the alias of a column in a select statement based on the 'name' in table1.

I can select the name value using xml path as below:

```
table1.TimeBucket.value( '(buckets/bucket/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(255)' )
```

I currently have the following SQL query, however it will not allow me to define the alias this way:

```
select 'test' as (table1.TimeBucket.value( '(buckets/bucket/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(255)' )
from table1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because column names are resolved at compile time not at run time for the SQL statement, only dynamic sql can do this:

```
declare @columnName as varchar(255);
SELECT @columnName = TimeBucket.value( '(buckets/bucket/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(255)' )
    FROM table1
    WHERE ID = 1; -- if you have more than one record in table1

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = 'select ''test'' as [' + replace(@columnName, '''', '''''') + '] from table1;'

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was imagining this would be the case. I understand the top section but am struggling to grasp what the @sql variable is doing? If I wanted to do add a select in the return value, where would this go?

Comment: @sql is a storage for you dynamic sql query

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. If I wanted to return a specific value from that table rather than the string 'test' how would I go about doing that? As in which part would I modify?

Comment: @Sean_myers, just replace 'test' with column name, which store that specific value

Comment: - if replacing with the column name (testColumn) for example:    set @sql = 'select ''testCoulmn'' as [' + replace(@columnName, '''', '''''') + '] from table1;'.  It will display the string testColumn. To display the actual column do the single quotes need to be reomved?

Comment: I have just figured this out, thanks for the help @Ruslan

Comment: @Sean_myers, glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this:

```
declare @table1 table (TimeBucket xml)
insert into @table1
values('<buckets>
  <bucket id="1" name="Overnight to 3 Mths">
    <lower>0</lower>
    <upper>3</upper>
  </bucket>
</buckets>')

select test = t.TimeBucket.value( '(buckets/bucket/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(255)' ),
              t.TimeBucket.value( '(buckets/bucket/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(255)' ) as test
from @table1 t
```